# How to get element by specific index in MongoDb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing, slice

```
{
  "_id": newDate("2/5/2015 15:00:18"),
  "bidPrices": [
    13.78,
    13.77,
    13.76,
    13.75,
    13.74,
    13.73,
    13.72,
    13.71,
    13.7,
    13.69
  ],
  "askPrices": [
    13.79,
    13.8,
    13.81,
    13.82,
    13.83,
    13.84,
    13.85,
    13.86,
    13.87,
    13.88
  ]
}
```

I wanna get prices from bidPrices which indexes are "1,3,5,6" .
All i know is use $slice , mongo will return a sub array of bidPrices.
Is there any way to make the mongo return such array:

```
[0, 13.77, 0, 13.75, 0, 13.73, 13.72, 0, 0, 0]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to return this collection of elements? Can't you just prune in your client code? If this is something you need to do frequently on many documents then you should redesign your schema to handle it. There isn't support in (2.6) MongoDB to do a projection like this.

Answer (score 0):

Using Map Reduce

```
var mapFunction = function(){
                                for (var i in this.bidPrices) {
                                    if(i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 5 || i == 6){
                                        emit(this._id, this.bidPrices[i]);
                                    }
                                }; 
                            };

var reduceFunction = function(key, values) {
                            var reduced = {};     
                                for (var i in values) {
                                        reduced[i] = values[i];
                                };
                            return reduced;            
                };

db.test2.mapReduce(
                     mapFunction,
                     reduceFunction,
                     { out: "test2_res"
                     }
                   )
```

Comment: Ok,I'll try it. But I'm worrying about the efficiency. Is there any one who can tell me about this?

Comment: It should be pretty efficient in your case.